# order by and limit when multiple matching rows present

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by, limit

I have a problem. my query is given below

```
"SELECT
mail
FROM
table2
INNER JOIN
table1 ON table2.wid = table1.id
WHERE
table1.time_stamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
AND
table1.status<>200
GROUP BY
table1.Id
ORDER BY
table1.time_stamp ASC
LIMIT 2"
```

I think most of you got the purpose for which I use this query.I need to fetch only 2 items at a time for sending email(,but when the below mentioned problem occurs the query will not send mail to one user).

my problem is when 3 rows having same time_stamp value occur it prints the first two starting from last but it never fetches the 3rd one.I don’t want to miss any user from email notification. **how can I resolve this problem??**

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned `LIMIT` on the query result to 2. Remove it to get all results or change it to 3.

I changed the `SELECT` to add more columns so that it easy to check the results when you run it.

```
SELECT table1.Id, table1.time_stamp, mail
FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.wid = table1.id
WHERE
     table1.time_stamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
     AND table1.status<>200
GROUP BY table1.Id
ORDER BY table1.time_stamp ASC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: no sir i can't change the limit. my client need to fetch only 2 items at a time. can u please tell me any other better solution??

Comment: if you only want two rows, why are you bothered about 3rd row?

Comment: but sir if this situation occur during running this project it will not mail that 3rd user about his downed site. that will be a negative mark for my project. so i thought there may be any other solution for this problem exist..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to do these in batches. You can [use `OFFSET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) to control where you start at in the results:

```
SELECT
mail
FROM
table2
INNER JOIN
table1 ON table2.wid = table1.id
WHERE
table1.time_stamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
AND
table1.status<>200
GROUP BY
table1.Id
ORDER BY
table1.time_stamp ASC
LIMIT 2
OFFSET 2
```

This would retrieve the second set of two rows, for example. If you set the offset value programmatically, then you can use this to go through the entire result set while only retrieving two at a time.

I believe MySQL also supports this through `LIMIT` alone, in the form of `LIMIT <offset>, <limit>`.

I'd be remiss if I didn't point out how incredibly inefficient and pointless it is to do this, however.

Comment: its prints only one value.. actually what is the purpose of OFFSET sir??

Comment: OFFSET skips first two lines

Comment: @Justin: so..can u plz tell me the exact solution??

Comment: @user007 I don't understand your question,  you don't wanna miss any user from email notification,  but your client need to fetch only 2 items at a time? "client" is some php application, function? If yes, you can select everything in mysql, then in php code make loop to fetch 2 records each time...